# I have an fltk Fl_Choice drop down in a window, but can only use it via the mouse

Tags: c++, user-interface, fltk

I have an fltk Fl_Choice drop down in a window, but can only use it via the mouse. Tabbing through the controls misses the dropdown. Giving focus to the dropdown with the mouse still doesn't enable up/down navigation using the keyboard. Is this a known issue? Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

tabbing not immediately apparent, but the dropdown is activated by the spacebar when it has focus. You can then up and down arrow through the values.

Comment: leaving this up in case anyone comes across the same (non) problem